# Странное отображение input в Opera

Tags: css

Почему так отражаются input Фамилия и Телефон в Opera? В chrome все в порядке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*SECTION SURVEY */
#survey {
  height: 700px;
}

.survey {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72, 94, 116, 0.7);
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: white;

}

.survey form input {
width: 90%;
padding: 1em;
}

.survey h2 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="survey">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="survey">

      <h2>Анкета для подбора образа</h2>

        <form>
          <p>

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" class="input" />
          </p>
          <p>

            <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Фамилия" class="input" />
          </p>

        <p>

          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="input" />
        </p>
        <p>

          <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Телефон" class="input" />
        </p>
          </form>

          <p>
              <a class="button" href="#">Продолжить анкету</a>
            </p>

      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Неправда, всё нормально в опере отображается https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dzLN.png

Comment: Странно. Если открыть с проекта, то поля Фамилия и Телефон отражаются на каком-то сером фоне. Ок. Попробую разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, вы забыли поместить в текст вопроса ещё какой-то важный код, который мог стать причиной этого явления (но какой — этого мы уже знать не можем)

Comment: Ок. Попробую устранить это

Comment: Можете порекомендовать какой-нибудт хороший курс по CSS кроссбраузерности?